# read a part of JSON file

Tags: json, sed, awk, grep

I have a dynamically created json file.
I want to know only the "errors" part of "status". Is there any easy way to do so?

```
...
a lot of lines 
...

 "status": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Input contained no data", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ], 
    "state": "DONE"
  }
...
a lot of lines
...
```

I need to use the output in a shell script so awk is preferred.

Comment: You should use a JSON parsing module in Python or Perl or a standalone JSON parser. Regular expressions aren't suitable for this task.

Comment: You can use a JSON parsing module in awk as well: see https://github.com/dubiousjim/awkenough/blob/master/README.lib and search for query_json. Just saying that to counter the widespread misimpression that awk is too lowpowered for this kind of thing. That said, I don't see anything in the question which makes awk more suitable than any of the other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^ "status": {/,/^  }$/!d;/^    "errors": \[/,/^    \],/!d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sed` to select a range of lines like this:

```
sed -e '/^    "errors\": \[/,/^    ],/!d' file.txt
```

result:

```
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Input contained no data", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
```

Consider adding expected results if I have misunderstood your question.

HTH